# How to capture all successfull sessions?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I have a sensor that will capture each stage of a user id's session state. So the session id has four types.

1-start of session

2,3-middle of session

4-end of session

The sensors will fail sometimes and not capture all the session states for an id.

So my data table is like below:

```
 DT = data.table(
  id = c(rep(1, 12),rep(2,4)),
  datetime = c(
    "2017-01-06 18:49:40",
    "2017-01-06 18:58:23",
    "2017-01-06 19:41:34",
    "2017-01-09 10:11:34",
    "2017-01-09 10:20:35",
    "2017-01-10 06:12:30",
    "2017-01-12 18:02:52",
    "2017-01-12 18:08:30",
    "2017-01-12 18:28:44",
    "2017-01-12 18:32:03",
    "2017-01-15 01:03:12",
    "2017-01-15 01:03:58",
    "2017-01-02 02:35:54",
    "2017-01-04 22:52:54",
    "2017-01-04 23:03:33",
    "2017-01-04 23:11:20"
  ),
  session_id = c(1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4)
)
```

From this, I wanted to get all the completed sessions(which can start from the first session (1 or 2 or 3) and must have an end session which is state 4) to compute the time of each completed session for each user.

So from this, I need to get the completed sessions as the follow table:

```
     resultDT = data.table(
  id = c(rep(1, 9),rep(2,3)),
  datetime = c(
    "2017-01-06 18:49:40",
    "2017-01-06 18:58:23",
    "2017-01-06 19:41:34",
    "2017-01-12 18:02:52",
    "2017-01-12 18:08:30",
    "2017-01-12 18:28:44",
    "2017-01-12 18:32:03",
    "2017-01-15 01:03:12",
    "2017-01-15 01:03:58",
    "2017-01-04 22:52:54",
    "2017-01-04 23:03:33",
    "2017-01-04 23:11:20"
  ),
  session_id = c(1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4,1,3,4),
  same_group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3,4,4,4)
)
```

So I tried to initially group all the ones finishing with 4 and filter then assign the same group by cumsum again.

```
DT[, same_group:= shift(cumsum(session_id==4L), fill=0L),list(id)]
```

But this one fails until a 4 is spotted (includes multiple sessions into one for some cases).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean computing difftime between 1 and 4 stages? By ID?

Comment: yup but that will be the last step.initially, I need  to get resultDT so that later i can take each min and max from each same_group and then just apply difftime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully there is a simpler way to do this, but it sounds like this is what you are looking for. Hope this helps!!

```
# Mark session_id 4 w/ group #
DT[session_id == 4, same_group := cumsum(!is.na(session_id))]

# Fill in the group variable
DT[, same_group := nafill(same_group, "nocb")] 

# Filter by removing duplicates in reverse (by groups) & ensuring the value is larger than the previous value
DT[DT[, .I[!duplicated(session_id, fromLast = TRUE) & c((session_id > shift(session_id))[-1], TRUE)], by = .(id, same_group)]$V1]
    id            datetime session_id same_group
 1:  1 2017-01-06 18:49:40          1          1
 2:  1 2017-01-06 18:58:23          3          1
 3:  1 2017-01-06 19:41:34          4          1
 4:  1 2017-01-12 18:02:52          1          2
 5:  1 2017-01-12 18:08:30          2          2
 6:  1 2017-01-12 18:28:44          3          2
 7:  1 2017-01-12 18:32:03          4          2
 8:  1 2017-01-15 01:03:12          3          3
 9:  1 2017-01-15 01:03:58          4          3
10:  2 2017-01-04 22:52:54          1          4
11:  2 2017-01-04 23:03:33          3          4
12:  2 2017-01-04 23:11:20          4          4
```

**EDIT**: updated with new example by adding `id` to last `by` statement. If you decide you want `same_group` to reset with each `id`, just add `id` to `by` in the first line.

Comment: Thanks but this do not work for some cases have like sequences 1,3,1,3,4 then it marks from the first 1  to 4 as the same group which is not. Is it because there should be an additional condition to break (1,3,1,3,4) into (1,3) and (1,3,4). So in general the session sequences can be only (1,2,3,4), (2,3,4) (3,4).

Comment: I can't say I understand. Can you update the example and results with a dataset that demonstrates the error? Also, it is possible this isn't working because I did nothing with the `ID` column (it is all `1` in the example).

Comment: I have updated the question and also for ID column we can use it in `DT[DT[, .I[rev(!duplicated(rev(session_id)))], by =list(id, same_group)]$V1]` like this right in the grouping

Comment: a bit strange when i run this I still get `2 2017-01-02 02:35:54          2          4` this row in my result though.Are you running this on the updated DT?

Comment: Ahh, I did it on the second DT, let me check it out.

Comment: @chinsoon12 I think the issue when we mark session_id 4 w/ group it also includes the row `2 2017-01-02 02:35:54          2` into the same group so I think there should a condition to remove those groups which do not have 4.So I tried to filter out the rows after taking a lead condition like below :
`DT[,lead_session_id:=shift(session_id, n = 1, type = "lead"), by=id]`
`DT=DT[session_id<lead_session_id | session_id==4]` and then applied Andrew's solution .But I don't think this a good approach or generic one.

Comment: Thanks @chinsoon12, great point--I forgot about `fromLast`!